# VLANs and Trunks on HP Switches

Tags: hp, switch, vlan, hp-procurve

long story short my goal is to configure 3 ports on an hp switch stack that can only communicate with each other, and nothing else on our lan. I created vlan 60 with 3 untagged ports. However, when I do a "display vlan 60", I see that there are 3 tagged entries. I attempted to remove these entries, but cannot because they are not access ports.

Will this current config accomplish my goal? I tested connectivity across the ports, and that they cannot access the LAN, but I don't know why those entries are tagged ports.

If no, how would one go about removing these tagged ports from the vlan?

[See this screenshot for the vlan config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wlxs.png)

EDIT- I noticed the "route interface: configured" and am thinking maybe this is why. We don't want any traffic coming in or out of these ports to be routed anywhere. Simply switched over the ports. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`no vlan 60 tagged bridge-aggregation1` etc should work for Provision switches.

If the tagged VLANs are not also tagged on the link's far end, the VLAN ends there, leading nowhere.